# Kafka Connect date handling of debezium generated events

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I'm using debezium SQL Server to track changes on a production base.
The topic is created, CDC is working like a charm, but when trying to use jdbcSinkConnector to dump the data in another Sql Server DB, I'm encountering the following error.

`com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: One or more values is out of range of values for the datetime2 SQL Server data type`

On the source database the sql datatype is `timestamp2(7)`.
The kafka event is 1549461754650000000.
The schema type is INT64.
The schema name io.debezium.time.NanoTimestamp.

I can't find a way to tell the TimestampConverter that is value isn't expressed in millis, or micros, but nanoseconds (would not work with microseconds anyway).

here is my connector configuration

```
{
    "name": "cdc.swip.bi.ods.sink.contract",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "topics": "swip.swip_core.contract",
        "connection.url": "jdbc:sqlserver://someip:1234;database=DB",
        "connection.user": "loloolololo",
        "connection.password": "muahahahahaha",
        "dialect.name": "SqlServerDatabaseDialect",
        "auto.create": "false",
        "key.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
        "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
        "key.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
        "key.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://localhost:8081",
        "value.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
        "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://localhost:8081",
        "transforms": "unwrap,created_date,modified_date",
        "transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.transforms.UnwrapFromEnvelope",
        "transforms.created_date.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.TimestampConverter$Value",
        "transforms.created_date.target.type": "Timestamp",
        "transforms.created_date.field": "created_date",
        "transforms.modified_date.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.TimestampConverter$Value",
        "transforms.modified_date.target.type": "Timestamp",
        "transforms.modified_date.field": "modified_date",
        "insert.mode": "insert",
        "delete.enabled": "false",
        "pk.fields": "id",
        "pk.mode": "record_value",
        "schema.registry.url": "http://localhost:8081",
        "table.name.format": "ODS.swip.contract"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I forgort to post the answer.
The property `"time.precision.mode":"connect"` does the trick

https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/connectors/sqlserver.html#sqlserver-property-time-precision-mode

```json
{
    "name":"debezium-connector-sqlserver",
    "config": {
        "connector.class":"io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerConnector",
        "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
        "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
        "key.converter.schemas.enable":"true",
        "value.converter.schemas.enable":"true",
        "database.hostname":"someHost",
        "database.port":"somePort",
        "database.user":"someUser",
        "database.password":"somePassword",
        "database.dbname":"someDb",
        "database.server.name":"xxx.xxx",
        "database.history.kafka.topic":"xxx.xxx.history",
        "time.precision.mode":"connect",
        "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers":"example.com:9092"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

there is a missing feature in the SQL Server connector - [DBZ-1419](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/DBZ-1419).

You can workaround the problem by writing your own SMT that would do the field conversion on the sink side before it is processed by the JDBC connector.

Comment: I gave a look at connect-transforms. I'm about to write a DebeziumTemporalConverter to apply the needed transformations. [link](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/connect/transforms/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/transforms/TimestampConverter.java)

Comment: Anyway, datetimeoffset is also a real pain in the a**, since SQL Server debezium connector change the offset to pass an iso 8601 String with GMT reference. Even if the time is changed accordingly, the timezone offset is now lost.